# Python visualisation 2 Bar charts in one plot grouped by Column and year

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

I`m looking for a simple solution to plot two bar charts in one plot. I have seen some solutions using subplots but I think there has to be a more convenient way.

As you can see I am ploting the .sum() of my column["VSU"] in two different years.

2014

```
data = df_obersteir.loc[df_obersteir["Abschlussdatum"].dt.year == 2014]
plot = data.groupby("Vertriebsfunktion").VSU.sum().plot(kind="bar")
```

2015

```
data = df_obersteir.loc[df_obersteir["Abschlussdatum"].dt.year == 2015]
plot = data.groupby("Vertriebsfunktion").VSU.sum().plot(kind="bar")
```

How can I combine these two code fragments in order to get only one graph?
It would be nice if we could visually differentiate the graphs by color. Thank you!

EDIT:

Y: I want the sum of my Column VSU / X: I want to have the members of groupby("Vertriebsfunktion")

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data and how the joint picture should look like. One of possibie approaches is to select data from both years in question. And what should contain *x* and *y* axes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi i can't see the data so it's hard to know which graph you want exactly. But I still give you an example of a use of plt.subplots and plt.bar which allows you to have two histograms next to it. I know you are looking for a solution without plt.subplots but there is no easy one to my knowledge.

```
   data1 = df_obersteir.loc[df_obersteir["Abschlussdatum"].dt.year == 2014]
   df1=data.groupby("Vertriebsfunktion").VSU.sum()
   data2 = df_obersteir.loc[df_obersteir["Abschlussdatum"].dt.year == 2015]
   df2 = data.groupby("Vertriebsfunktion").VSU.sum()


   f, axes  = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
   axes[0].bar(df1.iloc[:,0],list(range(df1.shape[0]))) # plt.bar(x,height)
   axes[1].bar(df2.iloc[:,0],list(range(df2.shape[0])))
   f.set_figheight(12) # control height
   f.set_figwidth(18) # control width
```

Comment: Hey thank you for you answer. I dont quite understand the syntax of subplot. Using your code i get "IndexingError: Too many indexers". Do I need to define an axis? If yes how?

Comment: To make a histogram you need on the one hand the values ​​of this histogram and their index. For example if I want to do a histogram on a population 1,2 and 3 and I have 10 people in population 1, 11 in population 2 and 22 in population 3. You can make this histogram like this: axes[ 0].bar ([10,11,22], [1,2,3]).

Comment: So to come back to your problem, I think you must first specify df1.iloc [:, 0] .tolist () to obtain a list of the values ​​of your histogram, then their index for example list (range (df1.shape [0]), to create a list [0,1,2 ..] which will be the size of df1, which finally gives axes[0].bar (df1.iloc [:, 0] .tolist (), list (range (df1.shape [0]). 
then do the same for df2

Comment: Thank you for that example. I did it like this ```data1 = df_obersteir.loc[df_obersteir["Abschlussdatum"].dt.year == 2014]
df1 = data1.groupby("Vertriebsfunktion").VSU.sum()
data2 = df_obersteir.loc[df_obersteir["Abschlussdatum"].dt.year == 2015]
df2 = data2.groupby("Vertriebsfunktion").VSU.sum()
values1 = df1.tolist()
groups1 = df1.index.tolist()
values2 = df2.tolist()
groups2 = df2.index.tolist()
f, axes  = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
axes[0].bar(groups1,values1)  
axes[1].bar(groups2,values2)```